# Nightwatch.js how to use the expect API to verify the page title

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to use only the [expect API](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-api) of [nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) to verify an html page title, but I can't get the command right.
My guess would be to either check the inner text of the 'title' element, or maybe its value, but It's not working how I would expect it.

If I run the following mocha test:

```
describe('Open Google', function () {
    var expectedTitle = 'Google';
    var uri = 'https://www.google.de';

    it('should assert the page title', function (browser) {
        browser.url(uri);
        browser.expect.element('title').to.be.present.before(2000);
        browser.assert.title(expectedTitle);
    });

    it('should verify title.text', function (browser) {
        browser.url(uri);
        browser.expect.element('title').to.be.present.before(2000);
        browser.expect.element('title').text.to.equal(expectedTitle);
    });

    it('should verify title.value', function (browser) {
        browser.url(uri);
        browser.expect.element('title').to.be.present.before(2000);
        browser.expect.element('title').value.to.equal(expectedTitle);
    });
});
```

The assert statement works as expected, but with both ways of using expect, I don't receive the page title.

Output is this:

```
Open Google
√ should assert the page title (4787ms)
1) should verify title.text
2) should verify title.value


1 passing (12s)
2 failing

1) Open Google should verify title.text:
    Expected element <title> text to equal: "Google" - Expected "equal 'Google'" but got: ""
    at Context.<anonymous> (C:\temp\nightwatch-test\test\google.js:14:18)

2) Open Google should title.value:
    Expected element <title> to have value equal: "Google" - Expected "equal 'Google'" but got: "null"
    at Context.<anonymous> (C:\temp\nightwatch-test\test\google.js:20:18)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using Protractor to me. Why can't you use .getTitle()

    browser.getTitle().then(function(title){
            title.should.eq('Google')
          })

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am writing some example nightwatch.js tests for a non-developer and would like the tests to use the same logic.

Your example would also be possible, but even more confusing for the person.
Nightwatch is not using promises, so the example with getTitle() would look like this:
browser.getTitle(function (title) {
  this.assert.equal(title, expectedTitle);
});